# Javascript generate dotted fonts on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am looking at ways to create Dotted letter fonts for alphabets from A-Z in a canvas tag . Is there an easy way to accomplish this?. I want to create a tool to teach toddlers how to write.

One way to achieve this is to have an image in the background but I'm looking to see if there is a better way to do this

Please point me to examples on how to do this or any suggestions on getting started.

Comment: It's meant to be printed. I don't think you need to create a webpage. I think you need some sort of vector drawing program. If you're program supports something like macros you can generate your drawings in a very short time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various ideas:

1. [Create a pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/GradientsandPatterns/GradientsandPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010542-CH4-SW17) and use that in your call to `fillText()`. This will not necessarily align the dots on letter strokes, however.
2. Create your own font out of strokes, and then draw it as a [dashed line](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_dashed_line.html) (my example).
3. Create your own font out of strokes, and then draw it using SVG with [`stroke-dasharray`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeDasharrayProperty).
4. Find a free font like [Dotline](http://www.fontspace.com/honey-and-death/dotline) or [Trace Font for Kids](http://www.fontspace.com/p-j-cassel/trace-font-for-kids) or [Print Clearly Dashed](http://www.bvfonts.com/fonts/details.php?id=45) and [embed it in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722292/using-a-custom-font-with-css3-html5) or [embed it in SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#SVGFontsOverview).