# Coordinates for dotted fonts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts, coordinates, html5-canvas

Inspired by this [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-google-bouncing-balls/), which

- draws the word 'Google'
- in form of many manually positioned circles / balls (1)
- on a html5 canvas,

at 1) e.g. this is an 'o'

```
new Ball(210, 81, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(197, 91, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(196, 103, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(200, 116, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(209, 127, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(223, 130, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(237, 127, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(244, 114, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(242, 98, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(237, 86, 0, 0, red);
new Ball(225, 81, 0, 0, red);
```

I would like to know, if there is a way to define the coordinates for the circles more automated. E.g is there a way to derive the positions from font paths?

edit: My aim is to map at least all regular letters (both cases) and numbers, which makes  a minimum of 62 characters.

cont.: People who stumble upon this question might also wanna take at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606945/javascript-generate-dotted-fonts-on-canvas).

Comment: you would probably have to have a map of all the offsets relative to a starting point and pass that into a function. the function takes the offsets and the starting point and draws out balls accordingly. The maps (which would likely just be an array of objects) can be stored and reused again.

Comment: Are you looking to determine how to place the balls by an automated system? So that by the use of a number of loops the places could be laid out easily, versus the forced typing out of all the positions? I mean, you could use the coordinates above to map them all onto a grid, then figure out what they're doing, but it seems like this is likely to be the sort of thing mapped out once by hand, with some sort of (0,0) offset, and then apply the vertical/horizontal offsets to each prelaid character.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I already starting some simple algorithm, where each letter is composed of `draw a line` here, `draw a circle` there. But than I wondered, if I really have to do this from scratch, even if I might not be too complicated. I thought of the solution to map all characters out by hand as well, and it might be the best fit here, but a more "algorithmed" approach could offer more flexibility (e.g. step-size between dots) and to me I would feel more the way to do it. Maybe the latter is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to derive the positions from font paths?

Not in Canvas or using canvas commands.

There are various programs that will turn fonts into SVG paths.

But you can't just use the points of the SVG path because, for instance, a bezier curve is only described by 3 points but may account for 1/4 of a circle. From those paths there are algorithms that will break paths up into a series of points (ie an "Q" would become 100 points describing the circle and a line).

You should be able to search for these individual parts easily enough.

The easiest way, really, would be to start with a pixel font ([like this](http://content.altfonts.com/img/V/I/Victors-Pixel-FontA.png)) and make each black pixel into a point. You won't get very good resolution of course, but it should be very easy comparatively.

Comment: +1 + Thx. Do you have any suggestion on how to convert the pixelfont to the corresponding points or is sth., which has to / should be done by hand?