# Use manually uploaded font file on hosting

Tags: html, css

Generally the fonts we are using in html or css, are declared with style/id/class like this `font:"Georgia, Arial, Garamond;"`. Which means first it tries to find `Georgia`, if doesn't find this then `Arial` and goes on with the next one. However I just want to know if there is any way to use a font by uploading on my hostserver.
 (the font which i have already downloaded from internet)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a custom font with CSS3/HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722292/using-a-custom-font-with-css3-html5)

Comment: Thanks let me trying with that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) web-site that will generate the `CSS` code for you.

Basically, you upload the font you want to use for your web page:

- and it will generate it with the necessary versions for cross-browser
  compatibility;
- also providing you with a file to download with the prepared `CSS`
  and the necessary font files.

See this [working example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10727272/giddyup-demo.html)!

**To better illustrate:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GiddyupWebRegular';
    src: url('giddyup-webfont.eot');
    src: url('giddyup-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('giddyup-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('giddyup-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('giddyup-webfont.svg#GiddyupWebRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Direct access to the font-generator [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)!

Comment: WOW!!......Thanks a lot lot lot Mr. Zuul........i am going on these website for having a look on it. :) :) :)

Comment: Use Font Squirrel all the time it is great.

Answer (score 0):

Use @font-face

```
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-   family: Delicious; font-weight: bold; src: url('Delicious-Bold.otf'); }
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/